# Netbeans 8.2 won't install due not finding jdk?

Tags: windows, netbeans, jdk

I tried to install netbeans 8.2 on Windows 7 Home 64bit.

First I installed JDK9 with JRE9, and I set up the environment variable, PATH and JAVA_HOME with the JDK Folder.

But when I try to start the Netbeans-installer it break up and says to install jdk properly, setting the JAVA_HOME, and try again.

Maybe I should rollback to JDK 8 or 7.

Is there a possibility to install netbeans ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's as you say. The NetBeans IDE 8.2 Installation Instruction page states requirements, which are:

> The Java SE Development Kit (JDK) 8 is required to install NetBeans IDE. You can download the latest update of JDK 8 at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads.
>
> The PHP and C/C++ NetBeans bundles only require the Java Runtime Environment (JRE) 8 to be installed and run. JDK 8 is required if you are planning to use any of the Java features.
>
> JDK 8 is required to use JavaFX 8 features in NetBeans IDE 8.2.

Even in NetBeans Release Roadmap, you won't find anything about support for JDK9, there's only an article that says you can [build NetBeans yourself](https://jaxenter.com/netbeans/using-apache-netbeans-incubating-jdk-9).

Comment: That's why, okay thank you, I will use JDK 8. The installer said I need JDK 8 or newer. Now it's good!